# How to check an input has a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, html-input

I have this code for autocomplete in an HTML input :

```
$("#myinput")
    .bind("keydown", function(event) {
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB 
                                   && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
            var results = [],
                selectionStart = this.element[0].selectionStart
                term = extractLast(request.term.substring(0, selectionStart));

                if (term.length > 0) {
                    console.log(term);
                if(/*input has string "where"*/)
                results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(table1, term);
                else
                results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(table2, term);   
            }
            response(results);
        },
        focus: function() {
            return false; // prevent value inserted on focus
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value.substring(0, this.selectionStart));
            terms.pop();  // remove the current input
            terms.push(ui.item.value);        // add the selected item
            this.value = 
                $.trim(terms.join(" ") + this.value.substring(this.selectionStart)) + " ";
            return false;
        }
    });
```

What I'm trying to do is if the input has string "where" in somewhere, then it will load autocomplete from table1, otherwise it will load from table2. How can I check if the input has that string? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check it using `typeof`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: you mean value in your input box ?

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed yes.

Comment: check my answer.. you can use indexof to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `includes` method.

```
var inputValue=$("#myinput").val();
if(inputValue.toLowerCase().includes("where")){
    //rest of code
}
```

Another method is using `indexOf` method.

```
if(inputValue.indexOf("where")!==-1){
    //rest of code
}
```

If you want to do this achievment using `regex`, you can use `search` method.

```
if(inputValue.search(/where/i)!==-1){
    //rest of code
}
```

```js
inputValue="awherea";
console.log(inputValue.search(/where/))
```

Comment: str.search is also applicable

Comment: I think `indexOf` is better since IE doesn't support `includes`

Comment: Could also use `match`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the strongest browser support, use [String#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
if(this.value.indexOf('where') > -1) {
   //doSomething
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get your text value and use indexof to find it .

```
my_inp = $("#myinput").val();
if (my_inp.indexOf('where') > -1) {
   console.log('yes');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`string#match`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjv6fHVz57UAhXIp48KHbPWApwQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fmatch&usg=AFQjCNEaCsGX6u_ojf9OuunEoTSmCYtEpw&sig2=dUxy1Oircu-_wNR2eACp0A) method use the [`ternary operator`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAnKHyz57UAhWKtY8KHSdOD28QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FConditional_Operator&usg=AFQjCNEyfU4zvkUJSNIonRwYQ86E1fetTg&sig2=G-MmeYEJicr1F0MuDPBrXQ) for return true or false

And also Some of the More method

1. [`string.indexOf()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwilsvm00J7UAhWDwI8KHZuWDRwQFggzMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2FindexOf&usg=AFQjCNHta1nnsoFXSKyAfwIVXU_6ISE6Yg&sig2=qFrFwmEtiu2gqKJCX7WHJQ)
2. [`string.includes()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjx0ous0J7UAhWHvI8KHbflAEoQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fincludes&usg=AFQjCNE7bVuQnlr5qIH1uUJk5DFILKtbaA&sig2=Beu3gw2LErpkKqA1fhs_WA)

```js
console.log('hello everyone'.match("hello") ? true : false)
```

For jquery you could use the [`contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) method

```js
console.log($('p').is(':contains("hi")')) 
console.log($('p').is(':contains("22")')) // not contains
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>hello hi</p>
```